# How can I disable and enable SSL in Apache (without a command if possible)?

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have Apache running in Ubuntu 14.04. How do I disable and enable the SSL mode without a command? What about with a command?

Answer (score 47):

As far as I know there is currently **no way** to disable SSL without command. With command, simply launch your terminal and enter

```
sudo a2dismod ssl
```

and restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

To do the opposite, use this command

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

and also restart apache2

Comment: and how enable ?

Comment: I've appended it to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For disabling SSL without a command you can manually edit the SSLEngine directive in your ssl configuration file (usually in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf)

change:

```
SSLEngine on
```

to:

```
SSLEngine off
```

restart Apache. I guess that requires a command...

for Ubuntu 14.04 and before use:
sudo service apache2 restart

for Ubuntu 16.04 and beyond use: 
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service

from: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html

Answer (score -1):

Only commands are available for disable and enable SSL

Locate your SSL Protocol Configuration on your Apache server with root permission. And type

```
grep -i -r "SSLProtocol" /etc/apache2
```

to disable

Type the following command to restart

```
apachectl -k restart
```

Comment: Is `grep -i -r "SSLProtocol" /etc/apache2` intended to update the apache configuration, effectively disabling SSL? Instead, this command simply shows which files contain the `SSLProtocol` directive. The better answer is above (http://askubuntu.com/a/709631/382980)